# jQuery add elements after every input

Tags: jquery, html

I want to add divs after every input in my form:

```
$("#step1 .left input").after("<div class='form_valid' id='form_valid_" + $(this).attr('id') + "'></div>")
```

but all generated divs have id = "form_valid_undefined". I dont know why becouse every input have an id.

Comment: That's because `this` doesn't refer to the `input` elements.

Answer (score 3):

[after](http://api.jquery.com/after/) accepts a function as parameter, so that you can refer to your input element :

```
$("#step1 .left input").after(function(){
    return "<div class='form_valid' id='form_valid_" + this.id + "'></div>"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#step1 .left input").each(function(){
     $(this).after("<div class='form_valid' id='form_valid_" + this.id + "'></div>");
});
```